# Remove/Eject hardware USB license key

Tags: usb, virtualbox, license

I have a machine running ubuntu. On it I installed virtualbox and I have two virtual machines one ubuntu another is a debian.

In addition on my host machine I have two USB license key plugged in. The problem is I'd like to be able to easily tell which of the virtual machines can have access to the USB license key. However my problem is that the first one that grabs it has the exclusive use of it.
Since they are special USB key that are, as far as I'm aware, not mounted but rather just there I'm wondering how I could tell the virtual machine that currently has it to drop it.

The machine that currently has control of the key provides this:

```
bisel@squeeze:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0529:0001 Aladdin Knowledge Systems HASP v0.06
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0529:0001 Aladdin Knowledge Systems HASP v0.06
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
```

Besides switching off the virtual machines that currently control the key I did not find any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to connect and disconnect your USB keys using Virtual Box device menu.

You can also disable it from the command line like this:

```
VBoxManage controlvm "VMName" usbdetach usbid
```

or

```
VBoxManage controlvm "VMName" usbattach usbid
```

This should allow you to script it.